# is it required to buy a wi fi router to access http://192.168.1.1?

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

I know this Question is not technically related to Ubunutu but let me explain my problem. I am planning to but a Wi-Fi modem+router recently. I was learning to access the setting and tried on my currently wired modem. Now I used 192.168.1.1 and it showed error. then i tried typing ipconfig in cmd (I was on windows at that time). Didn't got the valid IP config and then changed the setting on IP4 in network connections still it didn't work. Hence, my question.

Comment: This site is only for questions about ubuntu, for general computing issues please visit http://superuser.com/, you can ask this there

Comment: This IP is frequently the address of router web interface. You have no reason to access this address if there is nothing to configure.

Answer (score 1):

**Note :** This is a general answer to give you the basic idea behind the stuffs as your question does not seem properly directed (IMHO).

If you are on the network `192.168.1.0/24` then you can access any service on any computer within your subnet provided you have sufficient privilege to do so or not blocked by any firewall.

Typically `192.168.1.1` would be the gateway address of the `192.168.1.0/24` subnet as it is the first usable IP of the subnet. Now you are sending a request using `http` protocol to that IP address by doing `http://192.168.1.1`, if that host is not listening for any `http` connection then you will simply not get the required service. This is true if `192.168.1.1` is running Ubuntu or a wireless router or anything else you can imagine.

So to answer your question you need a service that is listening on port `80` (`http`) on `192.168.1.1` to access `http://192.168.1.1` .

Comment: Do you think this answer is helpful? Does the OP need to buy a router or not? ))

Comment: I might be wrong on the prospect but let OP clarify that..my answer to the question `How to access http://192.168.1.1?` let it be a router, a computer or anything else, also the networking portion is covered too IMO..

Comment: It is a correct and actually a good answer, but I am afraid it is a bit too complex compared to the question, isn't it?

Comment: @Pilot6: I see your point..also buying a router to get `http://192.168.1.1` seems an ambiguous term to me..lets hope OP can clarify them a bit more :)